# ExpressionEngine 2.8.1: in channel form date field gives error

Tags: javascript, expressionengine

I have a grid in my channel form which uses a datefield. This gives the following javascript error in my console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property ‘date_format’ of undefined
or in FireFox: EE.date is undefined

Now the datepicker for that field is disabled, and no javascript after gets executed.

EE version: 2.8.1

greets
Rick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are affected by [this bug](https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/20198) that contains the following solution:

Open up `system/expressionengine/fieldtypes/date/ft.date.php` and look at lines 168-172:

```
$date_js_globals = array(
    'date_format'       => ee()->localize->datepicker_format(),
    'time_format'       => ee()->session->userdata('time_format', ee()->config->item('time_format')),
    'include_seconds'   => ee()->session->userdata('include_seconds', ee()->config->item('include_seconds'))
);
```

**Replace** those lines with these:

```
$date_js_globals = array(
    'date_format'       => ee()->localize->datepicker_format(),
    'time_format'       => ee()->session->userdata('time_format', ee()->config->item('time_format')),
    'include_seconds'   => ee()->session->userdata('include_seconds', ee()->config->item('include_seconds'))
);

if (REQ == 'CP')
{
    ee()->javascript->set_global('date', $date_js_globals);
}
elseif ( ! ee()->session->cache(__CLASS__, 'date_js_loaded'))
{
    // We only want to set the date global once
    ee()->session->set_cache(__CLASS__, 'date_js_loaded', TRUE);
    ee()->javascript->output('EE.date = '.json_encode($date_js_globals).';');
}

ee()->cp->add_js_script(array(
    'ui' => 'datepicker',
    'file' => 'cp/date'
));
```